# PYSPARK: UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 515-517: ordinal not in range(256)

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, character-encoding, pyspark, iso-8859-1

Attempting to show my resulting dataframe using PySpark and am getting the error mentioned above.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, count, countDistinct, when, trim, isnull, concat_ws, concat, lit, substring, round, avg, max, min, length, lit, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

# Get stats for all columns in a table
def get_table_stats(table, columns):
    udf_to_string = udf(lambda x: str(x), StringType())

    # Populate dataframes
    table_df = sqlContext.sql('SELECT ' + ','.join(columns) + ' FROM ' + table)

    # New df columns
    table_headers = ['_column', \
                    '_max', \
                    '_min', \
                    '_avg', \
                    '_max_length', \
                    '_min_length', \
                    '_avg_length']

    # Cycle through each column, obtain main stats and put in to dataframe
    for index, column in enumerate(table_df.columns):
        # Selecting relevant column value and also the length of those values.
        # The values must first be converted to strings to obtain the lengths, hence the use of the to_string UDF
        length_alias = column + '_lengths'

        col_df = table_df.select(column, length(udf_to_string(col(column))).alias(length_alias))

        # Relevant aggregates are determined, given aliases and stored as a single row dataframe
        aggs_df = col_df.agg(max(column).alias(table_headers[1]), \
                                min(column).alias(table_headers[2]), \
                                avg(column).alias(table_headers[3]), \
                                max(length_alias).alias(table_headers[4]), \
                                min(length_alias).alias(table_headers[5]), \
                                avg(length_alias).alias(table_headers[6]))

        # Add the column name as a column in our results row dataframe
        temp_raw_df = aggs_df.withColumn(table_headers[0], lit(column))

        # As we want to concatenate each row of column results to return a full dataframe of results, we must
        # ensure all values are of the same type, thus convert every value to a string
        temp_df = temp_raw_df.select([temp_raw_df['_column']] + [temp_raw_df[col_to_cast].cast(StringType()) for col_to_cast in temp_raw_df.columns[:-1]])

        # Update master_df after each column results are aggregated
        if index == 0:
            master_df = temp_df
        else:
            master_df = master_df.union(temp_df)

    return master_df
```

Defining this code and running the following code gives me the error shown below.

```
    >>> mydf = get_table_stats(table, ['index', 'name', 'age'])
    >>> mydf.show()
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 515-517: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Anyone know is this a problem with Spark itself? Or is it a python problem?

I have checked the encoding used in my iPython console and it is 'UTF-8'.

Comment: Where are you getting your table from, is it from a csv or text file which might have encoding errors or have an unexpected value somewhere. It's not necessarily a problem with your function.

Comment: @GauravDhama It's coming from HDFS, it is in AVRO format